# How to fit anchorpane inside titledpane of accordion?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

[image: Screenshot]

How to fit this anchor pane (containing TestScript folder) to the titled pane "TestScripts"? I'm not getting Fit to Parent option in scene builder. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout options in Scene Builder:

[image]

Look at the "Max Width" and "Max Height" Properties of the `TitledPane` they are set to `MAX_VALUE` to indicate that this container can and should grow as large as its parent allows.